# Looking for a solid Online Semicha

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, internet, adult-learning, semicha

I would love to get a semicha online. ( I have a job and family)
I am looking at it as a mile-stone (a degree I am proud of), not as a source of parnasa .

Any program you know which is trustworthy?

I am sharp in understanding and relating halacha and have an excellent memory, yet I have **dyslexia**. (still make many mistakes reading regardless of how much I try)

Please provide me any guidance and support.
Shavoa Tov

Comment: Much related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/88204/15256

Comment: You should be interested by the [Semichat Chaver Program](https://www.semichaschaver.com) which is targeted exactly at people like you. Good luck !

Comment: @mbloch that program is not a semicha program per se, as they have stated, I.e. he won’t get Yoreh Yoreh.

Comment: @DanielRoss semicha is a very elastic term which covers anything from a yeshiva student who studied for a few years to the “rav hair” Israeli semicha which requires many years of intense full time study. SCP is at a high level but compatible with the constraints of a working family man

Answer (score 4):

This is an amazing program which I have benefited from immensely. One can recieve Semicha on Hilchos Shabbos and is under Rav Yehonason Gefen and is under the guidance of Rav Yitzchok Berkowitz shlit"a.

The link is: https://kinyanhilchosshabbos.com/

Answer (score 3):

See the Virtual Halacha Program [www.vhalacha.com](http://www.vhalacha.com) They offer an exceptional Semicha program all under the guidance of Rav Nebentzahl Shlit"a.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try Yeshivas Pirkei Shoshanim who run an online Semicha course.

First a little about them - they say on their [website](https://www.shulchanaruch.com/about/):

> Pirchei Shoshanim and the Shema Yisrael Torah Network provides educational information to anyone interested in learning Halacha and learning more about Judaism, in general. We are committed to helping people learn the Shulchan Aruch by offering a program featuring extensive courses and information. Smicha is attainable for those who are eligible. Regardless of your experience and teachings, we can teach anyone about Torah and Halacha and can also help enlighten anyone on how to properly pray, keep a kosher kitchen, learn Hebrew, and much more. You can complete the Shulchan Aruch program at your own pace and according to your own schedule.
>
> Shema Yisrael’s Revolutionary programs allows everyone to learn Halacha. It was designed from the ground up to support you in your PERSONAL journey into the depths of Judaism – it doesn’t matter if you’ve been studying Torah since you were born or if you are making your first steps. We are committed to help you receive the right teachings for you.

Within their framework of study, the **Level 2** course is a semicha programme. In order to qualify, one must have their Rav write a recommendation verifying that they know you well and that you are Shomer Torah WITHOUT Compromise and that you are known to keep all Halachos and live in such a manner. After that, your application is submitted for review. There are associated tuition costs. The submission form is [here](https://pirchei-shoshanim.teachable.com/p/smicha)

You can find some course samples [here](https://www.shulchanaruch.com/about/course-samples/) and you can ask them any questions that you might have on info@shemayisrael.com

They have [haskomos](https://www.shulchanaruch.com/approbations/) (approbations) from Ovadia Yosef zt"l, Rav Ezriel Auerbach shlita and Rav Meir Lau shlita

---

**UPDATE**

Another two options...

1. The [International Halacha Institute](https://ihitorah.org/) now run a very comprehensive semicha [course](https://ihitorah.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%97%D7%94.pdf) in four language options (Ivrit, English, French and Spanish) and features [haskomos](https://ihitorah.org/#rec) (approbations) from HaRav Shlomo Amar and HaRav David Lau.

2. There is a new programme entitled *Gaining Mastery of Hilchos Issur V'Heter* run by Rabbi Yehonason Gefen and is a structured online program for avreichim and working bnei Torah based on [Rav Yitzchak Berkovits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Berkovits)’s famous smicha curriculum. Sources are from the Gemara through to the modern poskim with clear explanations both in Hebrew and English. With email and phone support for any questions. Additionally there is an option to be part of the chabura with a weekly Zoom shiur (or to do it at your own pace).

The program begins on August 30th 2023.

For more information, tuition, and to request an application, email Support1@KinyanHilchosIssurvHeter.com or apply through their website [here](https://kinyanhilchosissurvheter.com/join-a55120137).

Answer (score 2):

Machon Smicha offers a flexible online program with shiurim and in-depth study guides, as well as dedicated teachers who will answer your questions remotely. To pass the tests, if you suffer from dyslexia you might want to supplement your studies with shiurim on YUTorah.org on yoreh deah, such as those of Rabbi Boruch Simon or Rabbi Aryeh Lebowitz

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Lishke and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

An option that I know people tried - including those with learning issues - is https://www.iyunhalacha.org/programs/

As they write at the bottom:

Yeshivas Iyun Halacha offers Semicha in Hilchos Issur V’heter and Shabbos to those who qualify.
To request a copy of our Semicha requirements email info@iyunhalacha.org

<sup>While I'm not affiliated in any way with the program, one of the founders is a friend of mine.</sup>