# Dayanus given by Harav Zalman Nechemia Goldberg

Tags: semicha

Harav Zalman Nechemia Goldberg gives regular Semicha both orally and via written tests that you can send back. Does he do the same for Dayanus? Does he even give Yadin Yadin Semicha at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to personally call him.
It depends on his strengths and abilities etc.

I heard that it's starting to be very hard to reach him at all nowadays, but doesn't hurt trying.

Comment: I've edited out the personal contact information that was included in this answer. Is this information either public or posted here with R'ZNG's permission? If this information is already publicized for the purpose of unsolicited semicha inquiries (i.e. not dug out of the whitepages), please [edit] the post to include your source for this publication.

Comment: Please do not edit personal contact information into this post without also editing in a credible source for the assertion that it is public information.

Comment: Rabbi Ullman one of his biggest talmidim posted it already here as well....

Comment: His contact information can be on this page: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16375/smicha-from-r-zalman-nechemia-goldberg ... He is very nice and easy to talk to (hebrew or yiddish only)